# How to Set Grid ExtJS on HTML body with 100% Height

Tags: html, css, extjs, grid, height

I'm using ExtJS Grid to show my data. 
Actually I want to show my grid with fully view from the start. 
But I don't know how to set height into fully view. I only can set the height with pixel (e.g. 600px,1024px, etc)

here is my html code

```
<body style="background-color:#D9F4FF;height:600px"></body>
```

here is my some ExtJS code

```
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Export Report',
    border: false,
    flex:1,
    store: store,
    columns: [
            { header: "No.", xtype: 'rownumberer', width: 50, align: 'center' },
            { id: 'hawb', header: "HAWB", dataIndex: 'hawb', locked : true, width: 80, sortable: true, align: 'center'},
            { id: 'mawb', header: "MAWB", dataIndex: 'mawb', locked : true, width: 150, sortable: true, align: 'center'}
        ],
    loadMask: true,
    layout: 'border',
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
        store: store, // same store GridPanel is using
        dock: 'bottom',
        displayInfo: true,
        items:[{
            itemId: 'filter',
            text: 'Filter',
            handler: function(){
                winFilter.show();
            }}]
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

so how to set my ExtJS and HTML code to show fully height view ExtJS from my browser.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a [`ViewPort`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#) with a [fit layout](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#) and put your grid in it:

```
Ext.widget('viewport', {
    layout: 'fit'
    ,items: [{
        xtype: 'grid'
        // ... your grid config
    }]
});
```

Comment: Or you can use another layout, like `hbox` or `border` if you don't want your grid to also take 100% of the viewport width.